# Android Programming help related to text field

Tags: android

i am creating dial pad but the problem is i am not good at android programming i need some help , i cannot get input in the edit text if i put clicklistner on one button it display the result but when i do the same with second button it removes the previous input , for example i want to get 0334534.. num like this from dial pad but when i click 1 it print 1 but when i click 2 it print 2 but replaces 1

```
{

package com.example.haseeb.dialpad;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final Button button1 =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final Button button2 =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


        final TextView textView2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);



        //button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //button.setOnClickListener(this);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                textView.setText("1");

            }         });




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use append() method

Change to this inside onClick() method

```
textView.append("1");
```

Comment: glad that this helps, please mark this as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your text each time you click on a button, like that:

```
textView.setText("1" + textView.getText());
```